# Getting Error:JRE_HOME variable is not defined correctly when trying to run startup.bat of Apache-Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, batch-file

When trying to start Tomcat Server through cmd prompt using 'startup.bat' getting error as-"JRE_HOME variable is not defined correctly. The environment variable is needed to Run this program"
Defined Environment path as-

CATALINA_HOME-C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59
JAVA_HOME-C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25;
JRE_Home-C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;

Comment: I solved my problem by the following link. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322378/jre-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-while-starting-tomcat/44322554

Comment: This happens when you have different versions of JDK and JRE versions.Please consider that too when u finding solution for this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Got the solution and it's working fine.
Set the environment variables as:

- `CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59` *(path where your Apache Tomcat is)*
- `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25;` *(path where your JDK is)*
- `JRE_Home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25;` *(path where your JRE is)*
- `CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\lib`

Comment: I suppose you meant to put the "...\bin" folders inside the PATH, not inside the CLASSPATH

Comment: All I meant to say was to declare the path in system variables and by default the variable name globally is Path.

Comment: this solution works with me for apache tomcat 9

Comment: Worked for me for Tomcat 9

Comment: This solution is not working for me while trying with Tomcat 7. Have set the paths alright, yet getting the error as JRE_HOME environment variable not defined correctly. Have tried removing semicolon as well. Not working

Comment: Tomcat looks for JRE_HOME first and if it is not found then looks for JAVA_HOME so you don´t need both, also you don´t need the CLASSPATH variable, just include JAVA_HOME at path variable (%JAVA_HOME%\bin;) and that´s it, important: open a new console to start your tomcat this refreshes the changes.

Answer (score 44):

Your JRE_HOME does not need to point to the "bin" directory. Just set it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25`

Comment: I tried but its not working.Still the same error persist.

Comment: Perfect answer...

Comment: In my case same problem in occurring.. I just simply removed semicolon from JRE_HOME and put like this C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25  then this problem resolved successfully.