# jre_home environment variable is not defined correctly while starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

When I am trying to run tomcat using `startup.bat` I get the following error,

```
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

I have even tried setting JRE_HOME manually to system variable list, but this issue remains.

My `JRE_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121;`

What can I do to solve it?

I am using Windows 8

Comment: How you set the variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope you know the way of setting path in Windows 8.
//**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121 surely as there is space between Program and Files, these kind of errors are possible. Please correct this path or store this in a path where no space is involved.**
  In Path add JRE_HOME path and click ok
    Reopen Command prompt window, then again give startup.bat

Hope this helps

Comment: In my case the problem was solved setting, in startup.bat,

<blockquote>
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
set JRE_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
</blockquote>

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue.

Firstly in your question it seems that the `JRE_HOME` is having `\bin`. This is not required.
Still you might get this error. So here is what I found to resolve this issue-

In the `running.txt` document that come with the Apache Tomcat says that it is better if the `JRE_HOME` is defined in `setenv.bat` file. This file does not exist on its own so you need to create it. The file has to be in `%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat` path and the content should be

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Java\jre8"
exit /b 0
```

`JRE_HOME` should be the path where your JRE exist.
Now you can start the server.